# Reference/PDF request for paper by Sathe and related note

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a PDF version of the following articles:

1. Sathe, L. G. - On a problem of Hardy on the distribution of
   integers having a given number of prime factors, (I. - IV.) J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.), 17, 63-82 & 83-141, 1953 , and 27-42 & 43-81, 1954

(note that there are in fact two articles here)

2. Selberg, A. - Note on a paper by L. G. Sathe, J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.) 18, 83-87,1954

Does anyone have it?

Comment: I earned the "Tumbleweed badge" for this question : "Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week." No one, really ?

Comment: Yes please ! Can you put them on a Web page ? Or in case, I give you my email.

Comment: Okay, here is my email : Yacine(dot)Barhoumi(at)rub (dot)de. I will erase this comment when I see your email. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  :) :) :)